# Не работает обработчик change с jQuery Selectmenu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Почему не работают ни `.on('change', ...)`, ни `.change(...)` с jQuery Selectmenu?

```
$('#sel').selectmenu();
$('#sel').on('change', function() {
    $(".advance").show();
});
```

Элемент `.advance` все равно не показывается. У него в стилях прописано `display: none`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что обработчик нужно добавлять для изменения Selectmenu Widget, а не для стандартного события `change`.

В [документации](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#event-change) предлагается два варианта добавления обработчика изменения состояния:

```
$("#sel").selectmenu({
    change: function() {
        $(".advance").show();
    }
});
```

И второй вариант:

```
$("#sel").on("selectmenuchange", function() {
    $(".advance").show();
});
```